# How to remove a link from content using php?

Tags: php, hyperlink

```
$text = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/file.php?id=name');
echo preg_replace('#<a.*?>.*?</a>#i', '', $text)
```

the link contains this content:

```
text text text. <br><a href='http://www.example.com' target='_blank' title='title' style='text-decoration:none;'>name</a>
```

what is the problem at this script?

Comment: it seems that it works.... i don't know what was the problem...

Answer (score 3):

[You can't parse HTML with regular expressions. Use an XML/HTML parser.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454)

Answer (score 1):

Tempted to flag your question, but there's no option for "Report user for summoning Cthulhu"

I'd recommend reading: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

RegEx is very poor and not at all intended to parse HTML. That's why there are HTML parsing libraries. Find and use one for PHP. :)

Answer (score 0):

use `<a[^>]+>[^<]*</a>` (works fine as long as theres just text and no tags inside the a element)

Answer (score 0):

USE strip_tags this way

```
$t = 'http://yoururl.com/test1.php';
$t1 = file_get_contents($t);
$text = strip_tags($t1);
```

it should work getting rid of all the links inside the page you are reading, visit the reference anyway, it may not work for complicated elements http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php